# Backing up current system's drivers

Tags: windows, drivers

Running a later model laptop of the win7 generation now running nicely under 8.1. Now I'm re-paving it and need to ensure that current drivers are available to the next install as painlessly as is possible. I don't want to wade thru the vendor's site hoping to coax them to give me 8.1 stuff when they have me of record at win7.

Is there a single place to go to copy folders off to a USB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I go about backing up/saving installed device drivers in Windows 2000/XP?](http://superuser.com/questions/29704/how-do-i-go-about-backing-up-saving-installed-device-drivers-in-windows-2000-xp), also see [Manually backup drivers](http://superuser.com/questions/537985/manually-backup-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

Drivers are stored in the `C:\Windows\System32` folder copy to them in the USB drive. But do take a note that if you replace the drivers for a newly installed version, Please restart the system.

If you are interested in third party softwares for doing your backup then try [Double Driver](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Double-Driver.shtml) and [Driver Max](http://www.drivermax.com/)